# Android Split ActionBar Padding

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, padding

In my App I have an Action Bar at the top of my screen which the padding is fine using this code:

```
<style name="TestTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">32dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

However this code has no effect on my Split ActionBar which I got when using this code in the manifest

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

This is what the Split Action Bar currently looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to give the buttons equal spacing/remove padding so they all fit onto the bottom of the screen equally? I've asked a similar question before, however I don't think I was clear in what I was asking. Any feedback would be awesome, thanks!